# Listening to offline application cache events

Tags: javascript, html5-appcache

Bonjour,

I'm trying to add a simple progress bar on my offline web app during the cache load.
I'm using [this article](http://www.jefclaes.be/2012/04/visualizing-offline-application-cache.html).
Here is "my" code :

```
function updateCacheStatus(sStatus) {
    $('ul.events').append('<li>'+sStatus+'</li>');
}
window.applicationCache.onchecking = function () {
    updateCacheStatus('Checking validity.');
};
window.applicationCache.ondownloading = function () {
    updateCacheStatus('Downloading');
};
window.applicationCache.oncached = function () {
    updateCacheStatus('Cached');
};
window.applicationCache.onerror = function () {
    updateCacheStatus('Bug');
};
window.applicationCache.onupdateready = function () {
    window.applicationCache.swapCache();
    updateCacheStatus('Updated');
};
window.applicationCache.onnoupdate = function () {
    updateCacheStatus('Offline OK');
};
window.applicationCache.onobsolete = function () {
    updateCacheStatus('Obsolete');
};
window.applicationCache.onprogress = function (oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.lengthComputable)
        updateCacheStatus('Loading...' + Math.round(oEvent.loaded / oEvent.total * 100) + '%');
    else
        updateCacheStatus('Loading...');
};
```

This works fine on IE and Firefox, but when using Chrome the page is frozen during the cache load and updated only once the process is finished, all progress steps are displayed simultaneously at the end. Which would make the progress bar I wish to add completely useless :)

I tried different things but no difference.
Does someone has a clue about this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: since it doesn't work on the low-level, you have to simulate it on chrome or abandon the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does mean 'low-level' ? How could this be simulated ?